# Unable to install spss modeller

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

I downloaded and installed ibm spss modeller 18.0. When I run the application, it asks for the mail id to start the trial period. After entering the mail id, the application just vanishes, and nothing else happens! I have got no mail either. What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. They ask me a code that they have never sent me.